# Bootstrap script not working in Blazor application

Tags: bootstrap-4, blazor

I want to use Bootstrap forms custom styles for a form.
As I can't add script in the razor file I have added it to the _Host.cshtml file instead.
But it looks like it never is executed. The form don't give any errors.

Any idea how to solve this issue?

_Host.cshtml file

```
<script>
    // Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
    (function () {
        'use strict'

        // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
        var forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation')

        // Loop over them and prevent submission
        Array.prototype.slice.call(forms)
            .forEach(function (form) {
                form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
                    if (!form.checkValidity()) {
                        event.preventDefault()
                        event.stopPropagation()
                    }

                    form.classList.add('was-validated')
                }, false)
            })
    })()
</script>
```

razor file

```
<form id="registerform" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="firstname">First name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" required>
            </div>
            // some more inputs here...
            <button id="btnRegisterSubmit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the blazor validation, you can change styles and classes conditionally (by using an EditContext you can get the validity of forms and fields in your own code). Maybe there is even a nuget package that wraps this.

Of you still want to go with js, use a named function and initialise your form from the first render (OnAfterRenderAsync)