# Bootstrap 5 validation message not showing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, blazor

I have a Blazor webpage using bootstrap 5.1.0 with the following form, the validation is purely client side:

```
<EditForm Model="CheckoutViewModel" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit" id="payment-form" class="needs-validation" novalidate="novalidate">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />

    <div class="row g-3">

        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label for="firstName" class="form-label">First name</label>
            <InputText type="text" @bind-Value="CheckoutViewModel.FirsName" class="form-control" id="firstName" />
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Valid first name is required.
            </div>
            <div data-lastpass-icon-root="true" style="position: relative !important; height: 0px !important; width: 0px !important; float: left !important;"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label for="lastName" class="form-label">Last name</label>
            <InputText type="text" @bind-Value="CheckoutViewModel.LastName" class="form-control" id="lastName" />
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Valid last name is required.
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <hr class="my-4">

    <button id="submit" class="w-100 btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit">Make Secure Payment</button>

</EditForm>
```

Everytime I submit the form, this is what I see, validation wise:

[image]

If I inspect the div that contains the invalid-feedback class, it is set to `display:none` hence why it does not show.

[image]

I've scoured the internet trying to find a way to display the validation message, to no avail. Some people have advise putting the `d-block` class on the div, however the validation message permanently shows if I do this.

How can I get the validation message to show underneath the input, when the form is submitted with an empty value, like this:

[image]

Comment: If you're using `<DataAnnotationsValidator/>`, don't you then also use the `<ValidationMessage For="() => CheckoutViewModel.FirsName" />` to do this automatically? By default, `.invalid-feedback` (and `.valid-feedback`) is set to `display: none`, and when the class `was-validated` is added to the `<form>` element, _then_ it displays. (You can see it in action here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/forms/validation/, and a screenshot showing how that property is changed: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0olN.png)

Comment: By "client side" are your doing validation in JS?  If not what not use the standard Blazor controls?

Comment: [Bootstrap script not working in Blazor application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65561008/bootstrap-script-not-working-in-blazor-application), because it's using [constraint validation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Constraint_validation), which is why it's not working here..

Comment: I have a basic example on how you can accomplish this. Essentially you want to inherit from `InputBase` and make use of the built in css/validation. I also provide a way to use bootstrap 5.0 validation icons. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73734223/591285

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to add the `ValidationMessage` component, like so:

```
   <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label for="firstName" class="form-label">First name</label>
        <InputText type="text" @bind-Value="CheckoutViewModel.FirstName" class="form-control" id="firstName" />
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => CheckoutViewModel.FirstName)" />            
    </div>
```